# Phalcon last insert id in aftercreate function

Tags: phalcon

How can i get last insert id, look like this :

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = 'asdf';
$user->save();
echo $user->id;
```

But inside models in function `aftercreate` or `beforecreate` function :

```
public function beforecreate(){
// last id ?
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to logs the sql statement into another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in the afterCreate. Please note the `exit;` for debugging purpose.

```
public function afterCreate()
{
    echo $this->id; // 8
    exit;
}
```

Unfortunately you can not access the id in **beforeCreate** because the record is not yet created, thus there is no id yet.

If you really need id in beforeCreate you could try to get current max value of the primary key and increment it with 1. But that's a bit hacky and using afterCreate is the preferred option.

Comment: thanks..

Do u think there is better if i use middleware events manager for listening each query in services rather than i use aftercreate in models?

Comment: It is all up to you my friend. If you have to log absolutely everything you could do it with [Events Manager](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/events.html) If you have to do some custom logic for some of the models you could do this in model events.